# How to avoid accidentally writing temporary source-block-edit-buffers to file

Tags: org-mode, evil, hooks, saving, literate-programming

When doing literate programming in [org-mode](/questions/tagged/org-mode), I frequently use `C-c '`[aka `M-x org-edit-special`] to enter the source-block-edit-buffer, so that I have appropriate [yasnippet](/questions/tagged/yasnippet)s etc.

I then accidentally save this buffer with `:w`, and end up with files like 

`Network.org[*Org Src Network.org[ graphviz-dot ]*]` littering my folder.

How can I avoid saving these files? Ideally, I would want the attempt to save the source-block-edit-buffer trigger saving the "parent" org file.

Edit: I now realize after the [answer from @lawlist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/39061/12504), that I was not having this problem every-time I save. Only, when I was using the `:w` [evil](/questions/tagged/evil) ex mode command, not with `C-x C-s`. I use both, depending which is easier in context to type. I always thought this was equivalent, so I did not mention it when I first submitted the question. Sorry, since this sightly shifts the topic of the question.

Comment: As for research: I have been reading around some on this site, and think, the answer should be some kind of function I add to a "save"-hook, which then derives the filename of the parent, and then triggers a save there

Answer (score 1):

There is already a built-in default keyboard shortcut to save edits (made in the editing buffer) to the parent buffer; i.e., `C-x C-s` -- which calls `org-edit-src-save`.

There are many ways to handle the issue described in the original question above.  This answer overrides the global keyboard shortcut for `save-buffer` by remapping it to the `org-src-mode-map` which is an active minor-mode keyboard shortcut map in the editing buffer by virtue of the `org-src-mode` minor-mode.  [Instead of `'hello-world`, the O.P. could use `'ignore` to have a silent approach with the same effect.]

```lisp
(defun hello-world ()
"Doc-string."
(interactive)
  (message "You have remapped `save-buffer'."))

(require 'org-src)
(define-key org-src-mode-map [remap save-buffer] 'hello-world)
```

Comment: +1, thank you for the effort. After your answer, I realized, my question was imprecise. Evil is involved, and only `:w` has the problem, not `C-x C-s`. I updated the question. I am currently looking if your answer helps me understand the new scenario. Please mark this comment obsolete once you've read it.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the Evil package, sorry.  I'll leave the answer for now in the event that it inspires you and/or someone else who may be interested in taking advantage of the `org-src-mode-map` to override other key bindings.  The concept is essentially to disable the keyboard shortcut that you accidentally hit, and/or remap it to a different function that you would prefer be executed instead.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. I will look for "1) Find the name of the current evil mode keymap of the org-src-mode-buffer. 2) find the function evil calls on `:w`. 3) in the org-src-mode-buffer hook it to call `org-edit-src-save` instead". This sounds doable, but I would still be glad, if one of the veterans could accelerate the process :)